# shortcode to show products by category woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I found on commerce website two following code

```
[Products ids="1, 2, 3, 4, 5"] 
[Products skus="foo, bar, baz" orderby="date" order="desc"]
```

One is used to show product by ids and second by foot. I want to show the product with **category**, but I could not find any shortcut for this.

**E.g** `[products product_cat="shoes"]`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: There is shortcode available for this. Checkout this [link](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-12)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try like this:
PRODUCT CATEGORIES BY SLUG

This will output the shortcode: [[[product_category category=”” per_page=”12″ columns=”4″ orderby=”date” order=”desc”]]]. Similar to product categories but this will output all products within the specified category and can be arranged with the per_page=”” and columns=”” parameters. The category slug can be found by navigating to the product menu in your WP admin and clicking on categories where you’ll see a list of all available categories and corresponding slugs.

See the below image which has option also

[image]

Refer this link too for more shortcodes : https://gplclub.org/woocommerce-shortcodes-full-list/

Comment: thanks rahul . i thought [product_category -----] is used to show the category list :) but thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own shortcode by sing following code. the code will return all the products in given category

```
<?php
function view_woocommerce_products($args){
    $cat = $args['category'];
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'product_ cat' => $cat );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>

    // Here you can access the product detail by using the $product variable

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query();
}

add_shortcode('view-woocommerce-products', 'view_woocommerce_products');
```

Here the use of shortcode

`[view-woocommerce-products category='[your category]']`

Comment: i try to do this .. but it will fetch all the product then i need to add my own html but with short-code html is auto written

Comment: and also where did you create shortcode you just getting record from database .